# Line break mode not working in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

```
CGSize expectedTypeLabelSize = [DealTypeSTR sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aileron-Bold" size:15] 
constrainedToSize:DealType_label.frame.size 
lineBreakMode:DealType_label.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: You should explain better what you are trying to achieve, what is the problem that you are encountering and the tries you've done so far...

Answer (score 2):

**You May try this**

```
 CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
     if ([label.text respondsToSelector: @selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)] == YES) {
        size = [label.text boundingRectWithSize: constrainedSize options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName: label.font } context: nil].size;
    } else {
        size = [label.text sizeWithFont: label.font constrainedToSize: constrainedSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this -

```
CGSize expectedTypeLabelSize = [DealTypeSTR boundingRectWithSize:size
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aileron-Bold" size:15]}
                                 context:nil];
```